# How many MB of data can I send (or save in draft) in Gmail per day?

Tags: gmail

When I uploaded a lot of attachments through Gmail, my account got suspended for a day. So, to avoid that issue in advance, how can I know how many MB of data can I send (or save in draft) in Gmail per day?

Comment: Really? I've never heard of such a limit. Gmail probably thought you were doing something malicious/spammy.

Comment: I'd suggest using GMail from local email client. Also if you're using it for data storage as well as emailing - mount your gmail account as remote hard drive.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Never heard of this either but I tried to find out what these limits are. Per their help:

- Maximum individual email size (including attachments) is currently 25 megabytes. [Source](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=8770)
- Maximum number of recipients per email is 500 (or 100 if you are using it via some POP or IMAP client). [Source](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&ctx=mail&answer=22839)

I couldn't find any specific reference to a daily upload limit but did run across this [Lifehacker post](http://lifehacker.com/141833/store-files-with-gmail-file-space) about a Firefox addon called Gspace that takes advantage of the amount of storage provided by Gmail. In their FAQ they mention that you can have your account suspended for 24 hours if you pass some upload threshold. However, no specific numbers were listed.

#### Via Gspace's FAQ

> **5. My Gmail account was locked for 24 hours. What should I do?**
>
> **A.** Wait for 24 hours :) . This happens if large amounts of data is uploaded or downloaded in a single day. So, try to avoid that. If you are lucky, sometimes even though the account is locked, you can try logging again. It might work. (It worked for me sometimes, I don't know the reason).

Perhaps someone with better googling skills can track down the exact limit.

Comment: It is good to note, that now Gmail includes features like Google Drive integration to allow you to use Google Drive to send emails. Also your attachments are included in your overall account storage limits now, so such a limit may be changed.